# Laravel+Homestead+nginx proxy: Getting the right url in my routes

Tags: laravel, nginx, laravel-5, homestead

I have a dedicated server with a Laravel 5 project and Homestead properly installed and working.
I just added a todo.app line in the Homestead.yml like this:

```
sites:
    - map: todo.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/todo-app/public
```

To access it from the outside, I configured an nginx reverse proxy like this:

```
location /todo/ {
        resolver 127.0.0.1;
        proxy_pass http://todo.app:8000/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Then, I added a line in the *hosts* file resolving todo.app to 127.0.0.1 and installed dnsmasq as resolver for nginx.

If I browse **http://dev.mydomain.com/todo**, I get everything working properly except for my routes: every URL the framework will generate will forget the subdirectory. For instance, the login URL is: http://dev.mydomain.com/login but should be http://dev.mydomain.com/todo/login. Changing the *APP_URL* in the **.env** file won't help.

Comment: I putted 127.0.0.1 instead of 192.168.10.10 because the network environnement into my dedicated server won't allow me to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried grouping all your routes and adding a 'todo' prefix to all?
Here is an example:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'todo'], function(){
    Route::get('index','HomeController@index')->name('Homepage');
    ... 
    //The rest of the routes
}
```

This could be your solution if your willing to touch your code for this installation.

If you need custom behaviours on the predefined routes and are using:

```
Route::auth();
```

in your routes file, you should remove the line and create your own routes.
You can use the following screenshot as a guide to see what the previous command automatically generates for you and use it to customize and create your own:

Please review: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ep9cD.png

You can use the:

```
php artisan route:list
```

command to replicate the image results in your own solution.

Comment: It doesn't work. My url to access my webapp become  http://dev.mydomain.com/todo/todo and the URL generated by the framework stay the same: http://dev.mydomain.com/login

Comment: What version of Laravel are you exactly using? 5.1 or 5.2?